# How do I add my text inside the border?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my text within my border that I added as an image. I will be adding more text and would like it to show up in my border as I am writing it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  width: 150px;
}
.main-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.main-nav {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}
a:link {
  color: #008B00;
}
a:visited {
  color: #008B00;
}
p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
#main-border {
  text-align: center;
}
.searchbutton {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-border">
  <p>Hi! My name is Marika and I am excited to join the school soon!</p>
  <img src="../desktop/background.gif" alt "border" height="500px" width="550px">
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot add elements inside borders although it's not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: can you make a fiddle please? I am a little confused by what you mean by "I am trying to get my text within my border that I added as an image". thanks

Comment: look up background-image css. I think that's what you're looking to achieve

Comment: @Paulie_D - but arent there trics using js where you manipulate writing around the image giving an illusion of writing like a border?

Comment: @Sai: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fq8qc3xf/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9ugcszgy/

Comment: @Sai It's not clear what the OP is actually asking for...but that sounds a little advance for this question.

Comment: If the OP wants to "wrap the text around" the image like a newspaper style, then try looking into a plugin called jQuery Slickwrap

Comment: You need to actually show us the image since we can't see what is on your computer.  Upload background.gif -- what does it look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not understand your question but i think this is what you are looking for :

```
<div id="main-border">      
  <p>Hi! My name is Marika and I am excited to join the school soon!</p>    
</div>

#main-border {
   text-align: center;
   background : url(../desktop/background.gif);
   background-size : 100% 100%;
   min-height : 500px;
   min-width : 500px;
}
```

Comment: sorry, I worded this terribly. I basically just want my text in the border i've added

Comment: @MarikaDevan - then try the code in this answer, that is what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

like this? obviously style to your liking

```js
var place=document.getElementById('txtplace');
function add_text(txt){
  place.innerHTML=txt;
  }
```

```css
#txtplace{background-color:grey;opacity:0.8;font-size:150%;position:absolute;top:100px;left:50px;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text_to_add" onkeyup="add_text(this.value);"/>
<span id="txtplace"></span>
                       <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600" id="background">
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking to achieve (although, instead of a picture of a kitten, your image)

```css
.THIS {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/500/500);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
height:500px;
  width:500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-border">
  <p class="THIS">Hi! My name is Marika and I am excited to join the school soon!</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but if you are trying to add text in the border you can absolute position it and do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/vo7jzz4m/

```
div{
width:250px;
height:250px;
background:url('http://placekitten.com/300/301') no-repeat;
background-size:cover;

border:10px solid transparent;
outline:1px solid green;
}

div:before{
top:0px;
position:absolute;
content:"aA";
}
```